# only one record is saving when uploading multiple images in yii

Tags: php, mysql, yii

Controller for image upload:

```
if (isset($_POST['Tblvehicleimage'])) {
  $company = Tbluser::model()->findByAttributes(array('user_code' => Yii::app()->user->ID));
  $images = CUploadedFile::getInstancesByName('image');
  if (isset($images) && count($images) > 0) {
    $line = 0;
    foreach ($images as $image => $pic) {
      $line = $line + 1;
      if ($pic->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot') . '/images/' . $pic->name, 0777)) {
        $model = new Tblvehicleimage;
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Tblvehicleimage'];
        $model->company_code = $company->company_code;
        $model->line_no = $line;
        $model->image = $pic->name;
        $model->save();
      }
    }
    $this->redirect(array('view', 'company_code' => $model->company_code, 'serial_no' => $model->serial_no, 'line_no' => 1));
  }
$this->render('upload', array('model' => $model));
}
```

Form:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'image'); ?>
  <?php
      $this->widget('CMultiFileUpload', array(
         'model'=>$model,
         'name'=>'image',
         'attribute'=>'image',
         'accept'=>'jpg|gif|png',
        ));
    ?>
```

This is saving only the first file, with line no 1. i want to save the second image with line no 2 and so on. Can anyone please explain what is missing in the controller?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add two more lines in your code and these lines might help you... every time the loop moves to next iteration you need to tell that its a new record so for it add this line

```
$model->isNewRecord=TRUE;
```

and then if there is a primary key in your table which is auto increment then you need to set it as null. Suppose ID is the primary key in your table then you need to do this

```
$model->ID=NULL;
```

So your final code becomes something like this

```
$model->company_code=$company->company_code;
$model->line_no= $line;
$model->image = $pic->name;
$model->ID=NULL;
$model->isNewRecord=TRUE;
$model->save();
```

**NOTE**: Here I suppose **line_no** is the primary key in your table. so You do not need to set its value each time if it is auto Increment in your table.Just set it as null.

Comment: TY mr. it worked perfectly. Anyway the line_no i needed to set; cause it's value isn't auto increment, it's part of a primary key. and value will start from 1 every time new data is inserted.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are re-using the same variable, $model, for your iterations. The values stored in $model are not being re-set, so, as @let-me-see describes above, once the record is saved it is no longer a new record, so on the next iteration it won't get saved. A simple way round that is to simply `unset` the variable $model once you are finished using it, before the end of the iteration. Your iteration loop becomes

```
if ($pic->saveAs(Yii::getPathOfAlias('webroot') . '/images/' . $pic->name, 0777)) {
        $model = new Tblvehicleimage;
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Tblvehicleimage'];
        $model->company_code = $company->company_code;
        $model->line_no = $line;
        $model->image = $pic->name;
        $model->save();
        unset($model);//Destroys $model, so your next use will start from a 
            //fresh, empty variable.
      }
```

Comment: hm..the idea is very clear to me now..thnx for the addition @Joe Miller